# Add a total bounty counter to questions

Tags: feature-request, bounties

Since sometimes questions get more than one bounty assigned, possibly awarded to different answers, it'd be a nice thing to see the total amount of bounties awarded due to the question itself. This would indicate that the question has been considered very important to someone, and may serve as an indicator to some of the most interesting question across SE. This could show up below the question votes in the overview as well, e.g.

[image]

(The bounty next to the title is an active bounty, while the bounty below the votes count includes a bounty of 100 that has been awarded before - maybe the + there should be replaced by a Σ)